# How to efficiently handle a Resource Object for a game in C++

Tags: c++, performance, object

I'm trying to set up a resource system for a performance simulation I'm working on, and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to manage in-game resource production from 1,000s to 10,000s of sources.

This is a hard question to frame but I will do my best to clarify as best as I can, the best way to start is probably with an example so I will give one here:

A building converts or produces resources of one or multiple types from a selection of up to 10s of different resources. I need a way to be able to easily get the total production of a building object ideally without having to check a number of member variables (one for each type of resource). My current solution is to have the Building return a Resource object which contains all of the different resources as double member variables.

```
class Building {
public:
    std::string name;
    int numJobs;
    std::vector<Pop> employedPops;
    Job job;
    Resource getTotalProduction();
    Resource getTotalUpkeep();
};

class Resource {
public:
    double energy;
    double minerals;
    double food;
    double consumerGoods;
    double alloys;
    double physicsResearch;
    double societyResearch;
    double engineeringResearch;
    double unity;
    double rareCrystals;
    double volatileMotes;
    double exoticGases;
    double zro;
    double darkMatter;
    double livingMetal;
    double nanites;
    double influence;
    double minorArtifacts;

    Resource getMultipliedBy(int factor);

    Resource(double energy,
        double minerals,
        double food,
        double consumerGoods,
        double alloys,
        double physicsResearch,
        double societyResearch,
        double engineeringResearch,
        double unity,
        double rareCrystals,
        double volatileMotes,
        double exoticGases,
        double zro,
        double darkMatter,
        double livingMetal,
        double nanites,
        double influence,
        double minorArtifacts) {
    }
};
```

I can't figure out a better solution but this seems to be just moving the problem. I'm worried that this will cause performance issues and be a pain to work with in the longer run if I or someone else wants to add or remove resources or add functionality.

Comment: You could declare a fixed array of doubles and an enum containing its named indices instead. Or move all of them to their own struct, put them in an array too and write a named accessor for each index.

Comment: While your question is on-topic for StackOverflow, you may try [gamedev.se] as well, they probably solve such problems much more often (I'm not really familiar with that site and I don't know if your question fits their requirements as-is, so please read their help pages before posting)

Comment: Your solution looks like it will carry a significant memory overhead for unused members. What's wrong with just having `Resource` be a class containing a `double` and an `enum` representing it's type? Then each building can just return an array of `Resource`s it uses

Comment: The memory problem was half of why I turned to here to get help. The reason I'm somewhat against it is that I want an easy way to deal with summation of large groups of resource objects, so having all of that contained within a single object would likely make my life a lot easier. The answer by DHMelon below seems to be the perfect compromise between your solution and ease of use which is why I'm trying that right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the STL pair function might be useful for this, at least for organizing. You can use an array/vector of `std::pair<string, double>` to store both the name and value of the variable. (Usage of an enum instead of a string would be advised)

Comment: That actually seems like it might be a pretty amazing solution, I will try and work with it and get back to this post later, thanks a lot.